# How and where to write function to use in layout(main.php) in yii2 basic

Tags: layout, yii2-basic-app

previously i made a navigation bar in a view page for which i wrote the function in corresponding controller but now i have to put this in main file (layout). But now i don't know where to write the function.
also i have to pass two variable to the layout file through the function that will contain the value of navigation bar.
I have already tried some method but it allows me to return only on value.
Basically i want to know that where can i write the below function to use it in main layout of yii2 basic

```
public function actionMenutest()
{

    $query = new Query;

    $data= $query->select('name,id')
        ->from('menu')->all();

    $query2 = new Query;

    $data2= $query2->select('name,menu_id')
        ->from('submenu')->all();


    return $this->render('menutest',[
    'data'=>$data, 'data2'=>$data2
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER** for this purpose. For advanced app the below code need to go into **common\config\bootstrap.php** file.

```
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\base\View;

Event::on(View::className(), View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER, function() {
    $query = new Query;

    $data= $query->select('name,id')
    ->from('menu')->all();

    $query2 = new Query;

    $data2= $query2->select('name,menu_id')
    ->from('submenu')->all();

    Yii::$app->view->params['data'] = $data;
    Yii::$app->view->params['data2'] = $data2;

});
```

Then in your **main layout** you can use your model as:

```
$data= $this->params['data'];
$data2= $this->params['data2'];
```

I have not used basic template as yet. But you can try the following:

Create a **bootstrap.php** file in **config** folder.

After that update the **web/index.php** file. Put the below code in that:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');
```

Then put the above code in **bootstrap.php** file. Try it and let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: one more thing i want to ask is that weather it is necessary to name file bootstrap.php,because i have tried with other file name and it still working

Comment: You can give any name you want.

Comment: okk... thanks once again. being new to yii may bother u again, hope u will not mind. ;)